# Using SVM from e1071 in R

Tags: r, svm

I am trying to use `svm` model from `e1071` toolkit,
simply like

> model <- svm(train_set,set_label,scale=FALSE)

and the original form of label for each instance is array like
[0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0]

Yet from this I would get the **error** :

```
 Error in predict.svm(ret, xhold, decision.values = TRUE) : 
 test data does not match model !
```

Then if every label is transformed to just one integer, it is fine.
So is it that the function `svm` just does not take array as output label?

Comment: Welcome to SO. 
To get better help, try to make a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Comment: It's hard to tell without seeing a reproducible example, however I would suggest ensuring that all variables present in your test data are also present in your train data.

Answer (score 1):

From the e1071 docs:

```
y - a response vector with one label for each row/component of x. Can 
be either a factor (for classification tasks) or a numeric vector (for  
regression).
```

What that means is that e1071's svm expects *one* label for each instance. It looks like you have 9 classes, represented as a 0-1 matrix. A factor vector with 9 levels should work. That could be done as:

`labels <- as.factor(max.col(labels))`